# How to set a custom emoji like a real emoji in Discord

Tags: discord.js

How to set a custom emoji like an emoji in Discord if I send a text message with **:bts**, the Discord client gives me an emoji but not an id.

I want to add that to Role `Reaction.js`!
Like if someone reacts with this emoji, the users gets a role.
If I do that **:bts:** he gives me an ID of the emoji like this:

[image: ID]

And if is another emoji from Discord, not custom like that:

[image: Discord text message with emoji]

That's exactly what I need, I don't need the ID of the emoji but the custom emoji like a real emoji in Discord. How can I get it?

Comment: please give us your code samples and trying. also read: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

That's how you can show your custom guild emoji in a text message:

```
const customEmoji = client.reactions.get('ID OF THE CUSTOM EMOJI');

message.channel.send(`Hey user! ${customEmoji}`)
```